# How to detect if a variable is encrypted in AWS lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

Is there a parameter in the `os`, `context`, or `event` objects that tell you whether an environment variable is encrypted, or less granularly if any variables are encrypted?

```
encrypted_db_password = os.environ['db_password']
try:
    print 'attempting to decrypt'
    db_password = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(encrypted_db_password)['Plaintext']
    print 'successfully decrypted'
except:
    print "Error decrypting, assuming a local environment"
    db_password = encrypted_db_password
```

Will attempt to decrypt a variable and on failure use the plaintext, but is inelegant and error prone. Is there a better way?

Comment: Environment variables just store data, they don't have any metadata attached to them to tell if their content is encrypted or not.

Comment: If the bits in a variable apperar to be random it is probably encrypted.